# How to chain methods of a UISelector object using Builder pattern?

Tags: java, android, android-uiautomator

I am trying to create a Builder class for the `UISelector` object. This is how my Builder class looks:

```
## UISelectorBuilder.class

package com.company.builders;

import android.support.test.uiautomator.UiSelector;

public class UISelectorBuilder
{
    /**
     * Constants.
     */
    private final UiSelector uiSelector = new UiSelector();

    /**
     * Returns the {@link UiSelector}.
     * @return {@link UiSelector}
     */
    public UiSelector build()
    {
        return uiSelector;
    }

    /** ****** USER PROPERTIES *********

    /**
     * Method to generate a {@link UiSelector} based on the provided Class name.
     * @param aClassName The Class name
     * @return this
     */
    public UISelectorBuilder addClassName(final String aClassName)
    {
        this.uiSelector.className(aClassName);
        return this;
    }

    /**
     * Method to generate a {@link UiSelector} based on the provided description.
     * @param aDescription The description
     * @return this
     */
    public UISelectorBuilder addContainsDescription(final String aDescription)
    {
        this.uiSelector.descriptionContains(aDescription);
        return this;
    }

    /**
     * Method to generate a {@link UiSelector} based on the provided index.
     * @param aIndex The index #
     * @return this
     */
    public UISelectorBuilder addIndexOf(final int aIndex)
    {
        this.uiSelector.index(aIndex);
        return this;
    }

    /**
     * Method to generate a {@link UiSelector} based on the provided resource ID.
     * @param aResourceID The Resource ID
     * @return this
     */
    public UISelectorBuilder addResourceID(final String aResourceID)
    {
        this.uiSelector.resourceId(aResourceID);
        return this;
    }

    /**
     * Method to generate a {@link UiSelector} based on the provided text.
     * @param aText The text to match
     * @return this
     */
    public UISelectorBuilder addText(final String aText)
    {
        this.uiSelector.text(aText);
        return this;
    }

    /** ****** UI PROPERTIES *********

     /**
     * Method to generate a {@link UiSelector} based on whether the object is enabled or not.
     * @param isEnabled True or False
     * @return this
     */
    public UISelectorBuilder addIsEnabled(final boolean isEnabled)
    {
        this.uiSelector.enabled(isEnabled);
        return this;
    }

    /**
     * Method to generate a {@link UiSelector} based on whether the object is selected or not.
     * @param isSelected True or False
     * @return this
     */
    public UISelectorBuilder addIsSelected(final boolean isSelected)
    {
        this.uiSelector.selected(isSelected);
        return this;
    }
}
```

I want to be able to create a `UISelector` object dynamically by providing only the information that I want. For ex: a `UISelector` could have just the `resourceID` while another one could additionally have `text` too.

I create the object using the builder like this:

`new UISelectorBuilder().addResourceID("resource").build();`

The problem is my `UISelector` is always empty. I have created builders previously using `ArrayList` and haven't had any issues, but this one doesn't seem to work. Does anyone ave any suggestions on what I am missing?

Regards,

Arjun

Comment: If you want some mandatory fields, set them as part of builder constructor

Comment: `The problem is my UISelector is always empty`, what do you mean empty, can you elaborate?